# user id goes to database null React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, frontend

I am trying to make simple function in React where when a user buys an item, their logged in username will be injected into the database. so far I have done it and it works, but doing the same for a different function, the userID goes in NUll.

```
//fetch user information from form
    const bookToBePurchased = {
        userFirstName: this.state.userFirstName,
        userLastName: this.state.userLastName,
        userAddress: this.state.userAddress,
        userId: jwt_decode(localStorage.getItem("token"), { body: true })["username"], // doesnt work, need to discuss
        bookListingId: this.props.bookListingId,
        transactionStatus: this.props.paymentStatus,
        paymentId: this.props.paymentId
    }
```

I have also tried the following

```
componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({userID : jwt_decode(localStorage.getItem("token"), { body: true })["username"]})
    }

  //post user input into transactions API
  onSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //fetch user information from form
    const bookToBePurchased = {
        userFirstName: this.state.userFirstName,
        userLastName: this.state.userLastName,
        userAddress: this.state.userAddress,
        userId: this.state.userID, // doesnt work, need to discuss
        bookListingId: this.props.bookListingId,
        transactionStatus: this.props.paymentStatus,
        paymentId: this.props.paymentId
    }
```

As you can see, in userId, when i console.log the jwt_decode, the rigth userID appears, when i set the state and then show a state, it still works, but when i place the value for userID, it goes in null. Not sure why. I tried so many solutions, on a span of 2 days, still no luck. In an another function, I have tried 2 ways, both of which works with another function, but not this one.

Comment: There are chances that your `jwt_decode` is returning null. Try printing that out first.

Comment: or you might need await before jwt_decode

Comment: @ShubhamVerma I do print it out across the page and it works.

Comment: @Mahi can you please elaborate?

Comment: @markhalawa Can you print out all state variable inside `onSubmit` function?

Comment: yes, every single one of them could be printed and shown in the database.

Comment: Please show us what is the value of `localStorage.getItem("token")` and `jwt_decode(localStorage.getItem("token"), { body: true })`

Answer (score 1):

I am not really a beginner programmer, nor an expert in SE, but this was a very rookie mistake. Since I was using spring boot as an api, the column names MUST match with the variable names in in JavaScript, and since the userID in question above did not match the column name i have in my springboot, it was treating it like, "new phone who dis?", hence the null.

There is something I want to share and I hope there are people who feel the same way but its always, with no exception that with programming, it's always the little things that causes the biggest bugs and can be really draining.